# Magento 2 ; Unable to pass custom params into the Save Button Of a UI Form

Tags: magento2, uicomponents

I want to pass a value/params via the save button of my ui adminform.

i tried this:

```
public function getButtonData()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
        $id = $request->getParam('id');

        return
            [
                'label' => __('Save'),
                'class' => 'save primary',
                'on_click' => '',
                'sort_order' => 80,
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter' => [
                            'actions' => [
                                [
                                    'targetName' => 'thechateau_magenest_bookable_save',
                                    'actionName' => 'save',
                                    'params' => [
                                        true,
                                        ['multidome_id' =>$id],
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],

                ]
            ];
    }
```

I can indeed see the values in the save button of the phtml page.

```
<button id="save" title="Save" type="button" class="action- scalable save primary" data-mage-init="{&quot;Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/button-adapter&quot;:{&quot;actions&quot;:[{&quot;targetName&quot;:&quot;thechateau_magenest_bookable_save&quot;,&quot;actionName&quot;:&quot;save&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:[true,{&quot;multidome_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}]}]}}"  data-ui-id="save-button" >
    <span>Save</span>
</button>
```

however when i try to retreive these values it comes up null.

```
$request = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');


$multiDome = $request->getParam('multidome_id');
```

I also tried to add it as part of the URL of the save button but it does not even show up on this:

```
public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save',['param'=>'value']);

    }
```

Comment: hi, find any answer? i have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any parameter to the submit URL. It can be useful to handle some cases in your's controller.
There is example of "Save" button.

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    return
        [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'on_click' => '',
            'sort_order' => 10,
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'your_custom_form_or_listing_name.your_custom_form_or_listing_name',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    true,
                                    ['custom_param' => 'qwerty123456'],
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],

            ]
        ];
}
```

You can change "Save and Continue Edit" button as well. Only don't forget to add to 'params' param 'back'.
There is example of "Save and Continue Edit" button.

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    return
        [
            'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'on_click' => '',
            'sort_order' => 20,
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'your_custom_form_or_listing_name.your_custom_form_or_listing_name',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    true,
                                    [
                                        'back' => 1,
                                        'custom_param' => 'qwerty123456',
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],

            ]
        ];
}
```